# PHP 7.1.5 Form validation error message inconsistency

Tags: php

I am trying to create a registration form with other input fields, below is a snippet that involves only the password field validations. Everything works fine up until password validation. It happens that the form only submits when i post a 5 digit or more numeric characters, but won't submit when i post a 5 letter long password. So it still echos "Password must be 6 characters at least" even when i post more than a 10 letter password. What am i missing?

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['pass2'])) {

  unset($_SESSION['pass']);
    unset($_SESSION['pass2']);

  $pass = htmlentities($_POST['pass']);
  $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;

    $pass2 = htmlentities($_POST['pass2']);
    $_SESSION['pass2'] = $pass2;

  if ($pass != $pass2) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Passwords did not match";
        header('Location: register1.php');
        return;
  }

    elseif(strlen($pass < 5)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Password must be 6 characters at least";
        header('Location: register1.php');
        return;
    } 

    else{}
}

?>

<html>
<body>
<?    
if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
  echo('<p style="color:red; font-size: 0.9em;">'.$_SESSION["error"]."
  </p>\n");
  unset($_SESSION['error']);
}             
?>

  <form action="register1.php" method="post">
    <p>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"  required>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="password" name="pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" 
    required>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strlen($pass < 5)` instead of `strlen($pass) < 5`:

So `strlen($pass<5)` will always return true, because `$pass` will be converted to an interger and will be equals to `0`, so, lower than `5` (except if the `$pass` string begins by 5 or more, e.g.: "6test").

Try this:

```
elseif(strlen($pass) < 5) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Password must be 6 characters at least";
    header('Location: register1.php');
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is just it, I have learned a whole lot from you, thanks. I am certain this will help newbies alike.

Comment: @UwemUke Thank you for your comment.